# Translate CONSTRAINT from PostgreSQL to MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, translate

How do I translate CONSTRAINT from PostgreSQL to MySQL?

```
CREATE TABLE language_history (
    pk int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    latitude double precision,
    longitude double precision,
    version int NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT language_history_latitude_check CHECK (((((-90))::double precision <= latitude) AND (latitude <= (90)::double precision))),
    CONSTRAINT language_history_longitude_check CHECK (((((-180))::double precision <= longitude) AND (longitude <= (180)::double precision)))
);
```

Comment: Just remove the constraints.  MySQL doesn't enforce check constraints anyway.

Comment: Could you help me with the code snippet? Thanks.